# Why Black Hole are black?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I found it difficult to understand what behind the story of black hole, I have did some research but have no sense what it meant. This question is really base on my curiosity, I want to learn and understand the meaning behind the black hole! Thank you!

Comment: This is a new one for Biology. Maybe on another site?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297890/rainbow-blackhole